# Laravel 5.3 Validation unique

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

I currently am struggling with the validation of Laravel, especially with the `unique` validator.

I have a table, which holds some values, the important one now is `templateUrl`. What I do is, show the user a form, containing the `templateUrl` he entered before (after saving it) and some other values, and then he can change it or leave it as it is. This `templateUrl` should be unique in this table. So if the user changes this `templateUrl` in the form, and its not used yet, everything is fine, but if the user now tries to save it, without changing `templateUrl`, then the validation throws an error (because this is already saved in the table, even if its the same row...). So it seems to be not possible to save the value, even if its the same row and column.. I hope you know what I mean?

This is the code for the validation:

```
$this->validate($request,
            [
                'templateUrl' => 'required|unique:users'
            ],
            [
                'templateUrl.unique' => 'Diese URL ist leider schon vergeben. Bitte suchen Sie sich eine andere aus!'
            ]
        );
```

What can I do, to make it possible to save the value, if its the same user, that "enters" or let the value as it is?
Ofcourse, no other user should be able to enter the same `templateUrl`, that's why I need such a validation, but if the user lets the `templateUrl` unchanged and just changes other fields in the form, of course it should work.

Any ideas, tricks?

Comment: Something like this - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/problem-with-unique-field-validation-on-update?page=1 ??

Comment: @SirjanSharma Yes, that looks correct but I don't get the values I need to use... I now tried this: `                'templateUrl' => 'required|unique:users,id,'.$user->id`, but it doesn't validate, so 2 users can have the same `templateUrl`, which parameters do I need to use?

Comment: @SirjanSharma got it, need to use the templateUrl as second parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra parameters to the validation to ignore a given row, in this case the current row. More information on this can be found in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique).

For example:

```
$this->validate($request,
    [
        'templateUrl' => 'required|unique:users,templateUrl,' . $user->id // Ignore rows with primary key $user->id
    ],
    [
        'templateUrl.unique' => 'Diese URL ist leider schon vergeben. Bitte suchen Sie sich eine andere aus!'
    ]
);
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the right answer, as pointed in the comment above. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So you can make something like below. Check if is unique only for others users, and only if user is found. This way you can use this method in update and store method. Anyway - better move this code to [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation).

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'templateUrl' => 'required|unique:users,templateUrl' . ($user === null ? '' : ',' . $user->id),
    ], [
        'templateUrl.unique' => 'Diese URL ist leider schon vergeben. Bitte suchen Sie sich eine andere aus!',
    ]
);
```